# Another process is updating "table", Records will be lost

Tags: acumatica

I'm getting this error, I'm updating a field after I upload an excel file, so its RowInserted event in DetailsForm, and at the same time, if the release button is clicked, it will update again after it was released.

The first PXCache.Update(DAC) was on my Function, and the other one where the error is occurring is on PXLongOperation.StartOperation() Method.

Here is my code:

```
private void PreLoadData() 
{ 
    PXCache cache = this.Document.Cache; 
    ISLoanRegister doc = this.Document.Current; 
    Loancache.Update(doc);
    doc.LoanAmount = loanAmt; 
    doc.MaturityValue = maturityamt;  
    this.Actions.PressSave();
} 

PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate () { 
        PXCache Loancache = this.Document.Cache; 
        ISLoanRegister doc = this.Document.Current; 

        Loancache.Update(doc);
        doc.Released = true;
        this.Actions.PressSave();
    });
```

Comment: add your code to the question

Comment: <!-- language: c# -->
private void PreLoadData()
{
            PXCache cache = this.Document.Cache;
            ISLoanRegister doc = this.Document.Current;

            doc.LoanAmount = loanAmt;
            doc.MaturityValue = maturityamt;
      


        }


  PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate ()
                        {
                          
                            PXCache Loancache = this.Document.Cache;
                            ISLoanRegister doc = this.Document.Current;

}

Comment: And where is the part where you are calling `PXCache.Update(DAC)`?

Comment: I used first PXCache.Update on Function PreLoadData();
and then Used Again on PXLongOperation thread.

Comment: Try first to do the following `doc.Released = true;` and then do `Loancache.Update(doc);`

Comment: I tried, same error.

Comment: Can you please add the exception with stack trace to the question

Comment: are these processing running at the same time? Keep in mind if the long running process is running first, your non long running process will need to wait for that process to finish.